How do I mounted a object data using axios in vue js
this is my menu page:
  <div  class="col col-md-3" v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="bg-image hover-zoom ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light"
                data-mdb-ripple-color="light" >
                <img src="" class="w-80" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <!--view product link-->
                <router-link :to="{name: 'viewitems', params: { id: product.itemID }}">
                <h5 class="card-title mb-3">{{ product.itemName  }} </h5>
                </router-link>

                <h5 style="font-weight: bolder;" class="mb-3">{{ product.price  }} $</h5>
                <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

my router.js
 //to view menu item :id
  {
    path: '/ViewDetails/:id',
    name: 'viewitems',
    component: ViewItemDetails
  },

while i can go to the product detail's page, i have trouble on how to mounted that product's data to the product view page.
 <div class="container" v-if="product">
        <div class="card" >
            <div class="container-fliud">
                <div class="wrapper row">
                <!--image-->
                    
                <!--Detail-->
                    <div class="details col-md-6">
                        <!--item name-->
                        <h2 class="product-title">{{product.itemName }}</h2>
                        <!--item description-->
                        <p class="product-description">{{product.description}}</p>
                   </div>
           </div>
 </div>
//this is script
props:['id'],

  data() {
    return{
        product:null
    //product: menuItems.find(product => product.itemID == this.$route.params.itemID  ),
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.fetchProductDetail();
  },
  methods:{
    fetchProductDetail(){
            axios.get(`https://localhost:44345/api/MenuItemModels/${this.id}`)
            .then(res =>{
                this.product = res.data;
                
               })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("fetch product detail error!", error);
                })
        },
  }

i try to run that code but keep getting this error:*
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}*

Is the id property set before trying to make the request? Can you access the route https://localhost:44345/api/MenuItemModels/YOURID when using a valid id from your browser? The 400 tells you that there is something wrong with the actual request.

the id is set in the database to be numbered in ascending order: 123... and the API is working just find every time I enter the id to search:
// GET: api/MenuItemModels/by id
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMenuItembyID(int id)
{
var item = await _context.MenuItemsSet.FindAsync(id);
 if (item == null)
 {
     return NotFound();
 }

 return Ok(new
 {
     message = "Success Get Method.",
     products = item

 });

}

@JustTuyen Can you share a reproducible example like a codepen or codesandbox link?

Can you log this.id in fetchProductDetail().

i tried it and it works! thank u

export default {
name: "viewproduct",
components:{
    Footer, Navbar
},
 //props:['itemID'],
  data() {
     return{
        id: this.$route.params.itemID,
        product:{}
    } },
    created(){
        this.fetchProductDetail()
    },
    methods:{
     fetchProductDetail(){
       // const id = this.$route.params.ItemID
            axios.get(`https://localhost:7067/api/MenuItemModels/${this.itemID }`)
             .then(res =>{
                 this.product = res.data;
                 console.log(this.product)
                
               })
                 .catch(error => {
                     console.error("fetch product detail error!", error);
                 })
       },
 },  
}

This is my method to get the product details. The good news is that fetching the data was successful. Bad news, I can't mount the darn things.
enter image description here
\Here is my product details template:
 <div class="container">
        <div class="card" v-if="product" >
            <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
                <div class="wrapper row">
                <!-- image-->
                    <div class="preview col-md-6">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
                        <!--button-->   
                           <div class="carousel-indicators">
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                            </div> 
                        <!--head image-->
                       <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" class="d-block" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" class="d-block" alt="...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" class="d-block" alt="...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--buttoms to move-->
                        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                        </button>
                        </div>  
                    <!--mini image under-->
                         <div>
                            <div class="slide-container">
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" />
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" />
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" />
                                <img src="../../assets/item1.png" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--Detail-->
                    <div class="details col-md-6">
                        <!--item name-->
                        <h2 class="product-title">{{product.ItemName}}</h2>
                        <!--item description-->
                        <p class="product-description">{{product.Description}}</p>
                    <!--Quantity-->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <h4 style="margin: 10px" class="Quantity">Quantity:</h4>
                            <!--abjust amount add-->
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                                    <path d="M432 256c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32L48 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l352 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!--display amount-->
                            <input type="text" class="number text-center" id="Quantity" aria-describedby="" value="1" required>
                            <!--abjust amount minus-->
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="15" width="15" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                                        <path d="M256 80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32V224H48c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32H192V432c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32V288H400c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H256V80z"/>
                                    </svg>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Price-->
                        <h4 class="price">price: <span>{{product.Price}} $</span></h4>
                        <!--add cart--> 
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-else>No Product details can be found</div>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>

